# Is it possible to initialize a vector and return it at the same time in c++?

Tags: c++, vector

So I have a question that involves returning 2 values as a vector on leetcode. What I want to do is after finding these two values, create a new vector with these values and return the vector at the same time. Essentially, turn the lines

```
vector<int> temp;
temp.push_back(a);
temp.push_back(b);
return temp;
```

into one line, hopefully something like

```
return new vector<int>{a,b};
```

Is it possible to do something like this in C++?

Comment: The syntax you posted works (once you remove `new`).... did you try it?

Comment: Ah. I never tried removing new. Thanks for letting me know. It works :)

Comment: C++ tip for you then: Never use the `new` keyword.  You don't need it, except for super crazy advanced stuff that most C++ developers don't know exists (placement-new).  Use value objects when possible, and `std::make_unique` otherwise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even more concisely, you can use [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

> 8. in a return statement with braced-init-list used as the return expression and list-initialization initializes the returned object

```
std::vector<int> foo(int a, int b)
{
    return {a, b};
}
```

Comment: Note: C++ has [a lot of initialization options](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization). It's in your best interests to be familiar with them so you can pick and chose the best one for a given job. Sometimes the options get, well, [nightmarish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs).

Comment: Oh god. This is so cool. This is super interesting.

@user4581301, a whole 1 hr video on initialization. Sounds interesting, and scary now. Going to take a look