# How to return a c++ variable inline?

Tags: c++, variables, inline

I am a bit of a C++ noob. I wanted to return a vector initialized with some default values INLINE

For python this might look like this:

```py
def random_function:
        return [1,2]
```

For C++ I tried:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> randomFunction() {
            return vector<int> vector {1,2};
    }
};
```

This gives me an error

```
error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
    return vector<int> arr {1,2}
```

Comment: `return vector<int> vector` → using the same name? You'll run into more problems very soon.

Comment: The syntax is actually simpler than you currently have. See [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66055843/is-it-possible-to-initialize-a-vector-and-return-it-at-the-same-time-in-c/).

Comment: yes ! I flagged it as a duplicate just now thank you!!